# Pointer Arithmetic For Intrusive Linked List

Tags: c, pointers

I've been looking at this [intrusive linked list implementation in C](https://github.com/robbiev/coh-linkedlist), and there is some pointer arithmetic that I cannot seem to piece together.

Firstly there is this function and macro which initiate a link node:

```c
#define LINK_INIT(linkptr, structure, member) \
  link_init(linkptr, offsetof(structure, member))

void link_init(link *lnk, size_t offset) {
  lnk->next = (void*) ((size_t) lnk + 1 - offset);
  lnk->prev = lnk;
}
```

I understand that `lnk->next (void*) ((size_t) lnk + 1 - offset)` is a pointer to the next struct in the linked list, but I don't understand why adding 1 allows the pointer to work still when the offset is number of bytes offsetting the member from the start of the struct.  In the [struct header definition](https://github.com/robbiev/coh-linkedlist/blob/master/intrusive.h#L9) the author says that the low bit is used as a sentinel to signify the end of the list, and so the `lnk->next` pointer can be &'d with 1 to test for the end:

```c
// All nodes (=next) must be allocated on (at least) two-byte boundaries
// because the low bit is used as a sentinel to signal end-of-list.
typedef struct link {
  struct link *prev; 
  void *next;
} link;

void* link_next(link *lnk) {
  if ((size_t) lnk->next & 1)
    return NULL;
  return lnk->next;
}
```

I'm just wondering why this works at all?  I vaguely understand allocation boundaries but I guess not enough to see why this works.

Comment: Very bad approach! Using bits in a pointer should not be done, unless you  have a very RAM-constrained target. And then a linked list is likely the wrong approach. And for a linked list, this is actually nonsense. Just use a _null pointer_.

Comment: How did you actually allocate these pointers? This `// because the low bit is used as a sentinel to signal end-of-list.` sounds very odd. I don't believe you can (ab)use a pointer this way.

Comment: Using the low bit of a pointer as a sentinel is a very bad idea, made worse by the cast to `size_t`. At the very least, cast to something sensible, like `intptr_t`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I'm not entirely sure, i stumbled upon this code on github, and it is a C port of this C++ implementation: https://github.com/webcoyote/coho/blob/master/Base/List.h#L162 , if that helps

Comment: _@AndrewStocker_ Just follow @Olaf's advice and use a NULL pointer as usual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree that Olaf's advice is correct in general, I am just wondering why this would work anyways

Comment: I think I know what this perverse code was trying to do. Based on [L178](https://github.com/webcoyote/coho/blob/master/Base/List.h#L178), it seems it tries to encode a per-node offset within each linked-list node, and the way it does that is by infecting the `next` pointer. The offset is then  decoded by `this - (this->prev->next)`. In effect, `next` points to the struct that the next linked list node intrudes within, while `prev` points to the previous linked list node.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist okay this makes a lot more sense to me now, thanks

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Actually, I used something similar on a very RAM-constrained embedded system. But then I used `uintptr_t` (converted to/from a pointer) and the bit was to determine the type of the target (some kind of data pointer). But that was long time ago. Things have changed. To encode a tpye, one should use a `struct` with a type-field and a `union` or `-fplan9-extensions` (gcc) and anonymous `struct` members.or any other more portable approach encoding the type in the object itself, not in the pointer **to** it.

Comment: @Olaf I completely agree, I am just a hobbyist and I am not making RAM-constrained software for embedded systems, so I absolutely do not need to manipulate bits in pointers (I would usually do what you said and use a union/type-field).  I am just trying to learn C and I didn't know how the above code even worked at all.

Comment: @AndrewStocker: Not every obscure code is worth to be explained/understood. To learn C, the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) is a good thing to keep under your pillow. While you might not understand everything, it will help to get phrases right and understand discussions of experts better. And - of course - practise it the best way to learn.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Hi! I know it's late for the party, but I'm wondering why does something like (size_t) m_prevLink->m_nextNode & ~1 work? I know & and ~ are bit operators (AND and Compliment), but what does this archieve?

Comment: @FanZhang Most platforms require that data be _naturally aligned_ in memory, meaning that the address of any data should (or sometimes *must*) be a multiple of its size, typically some small power of 2. Pointers, in particular, are often 4 or 8 bytes, so any data structure containing pointers should be aligned to a 4 or 8 byte-aligned address. `malloc()` must return memory sufficiently aligned to hold _anything_, since it doesn't know what you'll put into that memory. The consequence is that the lowest 2, 3 or 4 bits of a pointer to linked-list elements are always 0. Unless...

Comment: @FanZhang Unless some people try to encode useful information within those few bits. They do that by hacking the pointer itself so that is address is e.g. `(void*)((uintptr_t)ptr | tiny3Bitfield)` and read back the true value of the pointer as `(void*)((uintptr_t)ptr & ~0x7)` (_pointer's address ignores bitfield at the bottom_) and the value of the bitfield as `(void*)((uintptr_t)ptr & 0x7)` (_extract bitfield out of lowest 3 bits of pointer_).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks a lot for the explanation! I can see why it is NOT a very good practice nowadays, considering we do not need to hack bits to save spaces. But the offset is mandatory, right? It's just the way they do the offset is obscure, I guess.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Honestly I still don't quite understand some of the benefits of intrusive linked list, like they can be removed quickly. I'm going to read some literature on the topic and experiment with it for a while. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @FanZhang The data structure can be part of multiple linked lists, each of which must have its own corresponding member within itself. That member is at an offset within the struct; It can be computed with the C keyword `offsetof(struct S, member)`. See the question's macro `LINK_INIT`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks for the clarify. I read a few articles about intrusive linked list and they do give me some vague idea why intrusive linked list is useful. The thing is, each one gives its own implementations, and because I'm a hobbyist, I'm in no way to understand 100% of them. Is there a "typical" intrusive linked list that I can learn from?

Comment: @FanZhang Not really. The C language and its library come with almost no preconceived notions of how data should be organized. You're on your own to implement _everything_ (or reuse a library). As a result, anything more complicated than an array (trees, lists, ...) is always someone's homebrew. The only thing anyone say about a typical intrusive linked list implementations  that they embed one or more pointers within the `struct` to be listed. E.g. look at the `ListItem_t` within the Thread Control Block of FreeRTOS: https://github.com/cjlano/freertos/blob/master/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c#L305

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks, so I have complicated things. Eventually if the struct contains the prev/next pointer it would be intrusive, I guess. e.g. if I were to implement a dictionary with intrusive linked list, I don't even need to roll my own list implementation, I can just put `class Dict_Entry { Dict_Entry* prev; Dict_Entry* next; }` and write my own Dict_List class and that's done.

Comment: @FanZhang Yes, and that's how C development happens - if it were handy to have another struct member to put the struct into one of a small number of linked lists, then that intrusive member gets added. If the struct can be part of a large number of lists, or we're not allowed to change the struct, then one implements a nonintrusive linked list, at the price of extra memory consumption for the external linked list nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because most modern architectures are 32-bit and even 64-bit wide, and pointers must be aligned on 32-bit or 64-bit blocks; in that case, the int value of a pointer is necessarily a multiple of 32 or 64; so at least it is even.

**But** that is not always true. Just because the int value of a pointer is odd, does not mean that the pointer is not valid. It depends on the architecture.

Furthermore, when getting the "next" pointer, a test must be performed to return the correct value: `NULL`.

Incorrect assumption on the pointer value, extra tests, and risks using incorrectly the invalid pointer… Why not setting the pointer to `NULL` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I think the original author implemented the linked list to be circular, but I agree that it is definitely a heavy-handed implementation.  I was just wondering why it worked at all in the first place... but your explanation makes sense.